# Binding element 'navigator' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to build a mobile app, and I'm having some troubles with the react-native navigation v5, in their docs, I found this sample code, but both codes (my code and oficial code) are having the same error, Check out my code:

```
// In App.js in a new project

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

function HomeScreen({ navigator }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm having tis error: `Binding element 'navigator' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react-navigation passes a property called 'navigation' not 'navigator'

try changing the code like below

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```